# Where are all my methods of NavigationService and NavigationContext?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I can't see my `Navigate` method or for that matter any method of `NavigationService` and `NavigationContext` of `System.Windows.Navigation`. The intellisense doesn't show up. I can see only two method named `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals`. This looks very funny. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is intellisense broken in general, or is it just not working for Navigation framework?
Will your code compile with the Navigation code in it?